# DataGridComboBoxColumn Drop Keyboard Shortcut or Key Event?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DataGridComboBoxColumn in a DataGrid and when that cell is tab'd into, is there a keyboard shortcut that will drop down the list? If not, is there a way to hook a keydown event to that cell, then I would be able to set?

```
if (e.Key == Key.Space)
{
    DataGridComboBoxColumn.IsDropDownOpen = true;
}
```

My users prefer not navigate and update the datagrid only using the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of the question, there are two ways, Alt + Down Arrow or F4

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show drop down, press Alt+Down Arrow or F4.
If you want to only select any item press F2.